# Remove thin black frame around standalone image

Tags: tcolorbox, standalone, frame, tcblisting

**My MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  sidebyside,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}
  }
}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  comment and listing,
  comment style={scale=2},
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(1 = =2 = 2= 22=123=3= 13=1 313= 1 31=3131=3\)
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**The question:** *Is it possible to remove thin black frame around standalone result?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `frame hidden` to the comment style:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  sidebyside,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}
  },
}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  comment and listing,
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
  comment style={frame hidden,scale=2}
}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\(1 = =2 = 2= 22=123=3= 13=1 313= 1 31=3131=3\)
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]